# pygame: efficient way to draw traceline of moving object

Tags: pygame

This is  my case:

I have few slowly moving objects on the screen, the movement is irregular.
I started drawing something like a traceline, to see how they move.
I recorded all object positions and then I draw last 1000 historical positions as single pixel (pygame.gfxdraw.pixel). I also slowly fade the color on the oldest 100 (it looks better)

It becomes too slow when I have few objects and each has these 1000-pixel trace lines to draw.

I was thinking about setting the pixels on numpy array with transparency and then drawing the array on the surface, but so far, I struggle with creating such array with rgba and drawing it on the surface. Also, I'm  not sure if that would improve performance.

Do you have some ideas or examples ?
Thanks.[image]

Comment: Reduce the points, but connect them with lines. e.g.: [`ygame.draw.lines()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.lines) or [`pygame.gfxdraw.polygon()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/gfxdraw.html#pygame.gfxdraw.polygon).

Comment: Could you not draw them as you go? You should be able to get a decent frame rate doing that.

Comment: Have you tried looking into `pygame.PixelArray`s? https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html

Comment: Using lines must help, but will reduce the looks at some point. Not drawing as I go... hmm, need to take a look into it. About PixelArray, yes, this is my current try, I actually can draw numpy array, but not, when I add alpha. I guess i need transparency when drawing few arrays.

Comment: No it will not reduce the look. You just have to find the right amount of points. Pixels are integral. There is no point in drawing a point multiple times on the same pixel, but it has a huge impact on performance.

Comment: Can't you just save the pixels in a list, and only update the last pixels to black/fade color?

Comment: Ok, perhaps my problem is, that i fill the screen with black every frame

Comment: @jarekj9 No it is not. It is common practice to redraw the scene every frame. The problem is that pygame is slow. However, since you are not showing us any code, we cannot help you.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Likely the problem is that you have too many points in the points history. Screen coordinates are integral. Therefore, you only need to add a point to the history if the integral values are different. Store only integral unique points in the history:

e.g.:

```py
point_histoy = []

def add_point(x, y):
    pt = round(x), round(y)
    if not point_histoy or pt != point_histoy[-1]:
        point_histoy.append(pt)
```